# Why getting undefined while concating string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an empty string named **`newPassword`** and an array named **`passwordList`**. I am taking an item from the **`passwordList`** array and Concating it to the string **`newPassword`**. When I am printing the **`newPassword`** to the console it is showing **`undefined`** for some array items.

I have converted the number from 33 to 126 to it equivalent **`ASCII`** character and stored it in the array **`passwordList`**.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { newPass } from '../redux/slice';

const ItemMixer = () => {
  let {passwordLength, password} = useSelector(
    state => state.passwordLength,
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // converting number to equivalent ascii character
  const passwordList = [];
  for (let index = 33; index <= 126; index++) {
    passwordList[index - 33] = String.fromCharCode(index);
  }

  let newPassword = '';
  const generatePassword = () => {
    newPassword = '';
    let loop = passwordLength;
    while (loop--) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 126);
      if (randomNumber < 33) {
        randomNumber += 33;
      }
      console.log(randomNumber, passwordList[randomNumber]);
      newPassword += passwordList[randomNumber];
    }
    dispatch(newPass(newPassword))
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={() => generatePassword()}>
        Generate
      </button>
      <h3>Password: {password}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemMixer;
```

I am getting output like this:

```
45 'N'
100 undefined
37 'F'
123 undefined
```

```
72 'i'
112 undefined
50 'S'
46 'O'
```

Why I am getting **`undefined`**? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You should print `passwordList` and you will see why.

Comment: I checked `passwordList`. All the items is seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should multiple the `Math.random()` by 93 to get the random index because this is the number of items in `passwordList` ( 126 - 33 )

```js
// converting number to equivalent ascii character
  const passwordList = [];
  for (let index = 33; index <= 126; index++) {
    passwordList[index - 33] = String.fromCharCode(index);
  }

  let newPassword = '';
  const generatePassword = () => {
    newPassword = '';
    let loop = 5;
    while (loop--) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 93);
      console.log(randomNumber, passwordList[randomNumber]);
      newPassword += passwordList[randomNumber];
    }
  };
  generatePassword()
```